# java URLencode array of parameters to send

Tags: java, python, urlencode

It is possible to do the same thing in Java that does this python code?

```
params = urllib.urlencode({

         "param1" : var1,
         "param2" : var2,
         "param3" : var3,
         "param4" : var4,
         "param5" : "",
         "param6" : "var5"     
})
```

Is there a way to declare an associative array and make a unrlencode it?

Comment: Does this method encode for a _query string_ or form data? This is not quite the same thing. Hint: Java's `URL{Encoder,Decoder}` classes encode/decode form data.

Comment: encode a form data,It is possible to do the same thing in Java ?

Comment: Well then, `URLEncoder` is what you want; although it will not quite have the same syntax.